# Javascript does not accept HTML String from MVC?

Tags: html, string

Javascript does not accept HTML String from MVC?
My MVC contoller from where I am sending the HTML template in string from txt file

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Templates\NewGridTemplate.txt"))
            {
                // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                obj.sGridTemplate = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
                //Console.WriteLine(line);
            }


            return View(obj);
```

Actual code in csHTMl Javascript

```
  var sHTML=$(@Model.sGridTemplate);
```

Below is screen shot for error . HTML string  is not accepted by Javascript. shows character "<" etc.. Please help let me know what I missed.[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2I1K.png)

Comment: The string isn't quoted, so it's interpreted as syntax. Also, your MVC system seems to escape the string. If you want it to work as HTML, you need to turn this escaping off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your content within quotes so that it becomes a Javascript string, otherwise it'll be interpreted as syntax and you get the error because it's not valid JS syntax

```
var sHTML=$('@Model.sGridTemplate');
```

And the problematic line in the resulting client-side code should look more like this:

```
var sHTML=$('    &lt; ...
```

... than:

```
var sHTML=$(    &lt; ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. That helped me.